# About two Standard Representations of S3

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, irreducible-representation

https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Standard_representation_of_symmetric_group:S3
Gives two 2-D irreducible representations for S3. One in the basis (e1-e2) and (e2-e3) and another "viewed as a quotient" in the basis $\overline{e1}$ and $\overline{e2}$. There is enough information given about the basis (e1-e2) and (e2-e3) that I can develop the 2-D matrices for it, but there is no information about the basis $\overline{e1}$ and $\overline{e2}$. I am not sure what "viewed as a quotient" would mean in this context.

Could someone please provide an explicit example or cite one illustrating how the $\overline{e1}$ and $\overline{e2}$ basis is used?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! Doesn't the table at the page literally say what the 2D matrices are? Are you just asking generally about what a quotient representation is? If so, can you say a little bit about what your mathematical background is and what your motivations are here? It may make it easier to write a useful answer for you.

Comment: Yes!, I want to understand how those matrices are obtained.

Comment: Are you familiar with any abstract linear algebra? Do you know what it means to consider the quotient vector space $V/W$ if $W$ is a linear subspace of $V$? In this case, there is a natural representation of $S_3$ obtained by permuting the basis vectors of a $3$-dimensional vector space. There is a subspace on which the action is trivial, and the quotient by this subspace inherits a linear action of $S_3$. The cosets of any two of the original basis vectors form a basis for this quotient. I'm guessing this doesn't all make sense to you. Can you say what you don't understand/what you do know?